# JS tabs - show content only after mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, hover, mouseover

I am looking for some solution for this:
I need something like this: `http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#mouseover`
But with some default content block (without tab mennu item) and show other items only which `mouseover` is on some item. When cursor is gone from item then show default block again.
Basically same effect like this: [**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RM3yr/2/)

I can not JS, so I m looking for ready-made solution.

Thanks a lot

Comment: "You can not JS" but you still add JavaScript and jQuery tags oO Well you can use CSS and HTML anchors, or if you don't care about dirtness, flash, if that exists. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution with JS ..I know you dont want to JS but still have a look

```
$(function() {
    $("#products").tabs("div.description", {event: 'mouseover'});
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/RM3yr/210/)

Comment: Looks great, but have you some tip how I can add some default ittem (now is default first item - free version). I need that text without title (so only text without Free version). So in initial state no item hover, only default text.

Comment: Well i tryed it but its not solution for my problem, because its the exactly same like Jquery tabs in my question. I need this one but when you take cursor away from tab name/title/link then show default text again.